# trigger host app from INSendMessageIntent Handler method in sirikit extension

Tags: ios, swift

i am stuck with the following problem.

i want to open the host app from INSendMessageIntent Handler method.

i cannot find continueInApp option.

Comment: your ? is not clear

Comment: Please show us what you've tried so we can assist you.

Comment: Any solution on this?